# Custom walker to generate menu with integrated breadcrumb dropdowns

Tags: breadcrumb

Have been trying to write a custom walker class which returns a wp_custom_menu as follows.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC5cP.png

Planning to enhance the different states with some scripting. The page at http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/169/jQuery-Plugin-xBreadcrumbs-Extended-Breadcrumbs-navigation is a good example of the planned end result.

Could not find any leads nor howtos, some ideas would be fabulous!

Many thanks,

F.

Answer (score 1):

This not exactly a custom walker, but it has the same result: ["Breadcrumbs Trail Navigation"](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/breadcrumbs-trail-nav).

It can be used as

- A Plugin
- Part of your theme

If you want to integrate it in your theme, simply put it in your theme, `include_once` the file and you're done. On the github link you'll find a long readme that explains everything pretty well.